# Problem with updating apps in iPad 3 with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, ipad, auto-update

I have an iPad 3 with iOS 7.1. From April, 2014 I am having this strange problem. My iPad Apps won't update both manually and automatically. Every time I have to "Reset all settings" in the iPad and then only the apps would update. So please suggest how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you Jailbreak your phone?

If no, try go to Settings->iTunes & AppStore and turn on automatic updates. And make sure you have update you iOS version and check if you have enough storage space to download update.